# why installing python3 creates a shortcut in the location of default python(python 2.7) installation folder on mac?

Tags: python, pycharm

why installing python3 creates a shortcut in the location of default python(python 2.7) installation folder on mac? Also when we uninstall the later version it doesn't get deleted. I also found out that PyCharm configuration points to this shortcut file instead of the interpreter from the 3.7 folders. Can anyone explain why is this behavior or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: pycharm is just dropping subtle hints that its time to move on. *wink*

Comment: *How* did you install python3? When you say it "creates a shortcut in the location", do you mean python3 *replaces* python2 or that it is placed next to it?

Comment: No.. it did not replace it.. it created a shortcut for the python3 file alongside the existing python (python 2) file.